# I just wanna to delete favorites from firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase

I tried this code but this wasn't working anyone helps me with this.[The Firebase structure from which I wanna delete favorites item].

```
  void DelFavorites(final CardModel model) {
        final DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("User").child("Favorites")
                .child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid());
        final Query applesQuery = ref.orderByChild("key").equalTo(model.getKey());
        applesQuery.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
              //  for (DataSnapshot appleSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

                    dataSnapshot.getRef().removeValue().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                                Toast.makeText(context, "favorites removed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            } else {

                            }
                        }
                    });

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                Toast.makeText(context, "Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: What is your actual question? What "didn't work" about it? Did you get errors? What else, if anything, have you tried?

Comment: I add an event to favorites on button click from activty and now when i opne favorites fragment where all favorites list show delete the item on which is clicked.

Comment: When i tried this code it deleted the parent node of favorites but i juat wanna to del key node of spefic xlikced ite